# Druid Wild Shape to Wild Shape

Tags: dnd-5e, druid

I am a lvl 6 moon Druid at the moment. I was disguised as a cat when my party ran into a fight. When it seemed like my party needed my help I decided to jump in (literally) and help.

The question I have is: do I first need to change back into my elfen form before I can change into another shape OR can I instantly change to a new form ( while leaping at the enemy for example).

In the end my DM decided that I was able to change instantly but I would like to know if there is an official rule for this, for future reference.

I have not found anything on this in the player handbook.

Comment: Did not find that one. Thanks for linking and sorry for duplicate.

Comment: Dupes are fine. They help indexing the duped question (people might use search terms that hit this question, but not the other one). keep asking.